# Brackets & xdebug PHP on Linux

Tags: php, xdebug, brackets

I have installed xdebug on openSUSE and Brackets for editing. I have plugin "PHP Debugger for Brackets" installed.

I tried all the possible notes from various forum, I still get a message 'An active debugging session is required for code evaluation'

php.ini configuration:

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension=/usr/lib64/xdebug.so
xdebug.idekey=idekey
xdebug.remote_enable=true
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

Added `?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=xdebug` at the end of URL .

What else I am missing why is the debug session not establishing?

[image: PHP configuration]

Comment: Your screenshot (general info from `phpinfo()` output) does not show that xdebug is installed. Have you restarted Apache after making changes in php.ini? Have you edited the right php.ini (you may have more than one)?

Answer (score 0):

Your idekey should match the parameter you are sending to start the xdebug session.  Based on the information you posted in your question that should be:

```
?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=idekey
```

Comment: I tried using the command you have mentioned, it does not respond